# Conditionally Update a Part of State with useState

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-state-management, use-state

I am trying to update my state to include the new information object *if* the name of that new information object has the same name as one in the state. For example....

when new information:

```
{
serviceName:
    name: A
    properties:{
    cost: 300
    service:"Good"
    }
}
```

matches the name of an existing state:

```
{
serviceName:
    name: A
    properties:{
    cost: 600
    service:"Bad"
    }
}
```

The goal is that I can then merge *just* the properties, resulting in:

```
{
serviceName:
    name: A
    properties:{
    cost: [300,600]
    service:["Good", "Bad"]
    }
}
```

The closest I've gotten works on the first match, but subsequent matches results in an array of arrays, like so (three items matched, so there should have been an array with 3 items in cost and service):

```
{
    "name": "State",
    "value": [
      {
        "serviceName": {
          "name": "Informational Website - subscription",
          "properties": {
            "service": [
              [
                "Mobile-ready, Responsive Design",
                "Blog Articles"
              ],
              "Collect visitor information (email / phone)"
            ],
            "cost": [
              [
                "300",
                "500"
              ],
              "500"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "subHooks": []
  },
```

I achieved the above with the following code:

```
  const [informationalService, setInformationalService] = useState([]);

  const handleChecking = (e, item) => {
    const { name } = e.target;
    if (informationalService.length > 0) {
      const selectedName = informationalService.filter(
        selection => selection.serviceName.name === name
      );

      const selectedNamePropertiesCost = selectedName.map(
        prop => prop.serviceName.properties.cost
      );

      const selectedNamePropertiesService = selectedName.map(
        prop => prop.serviceName.properties.service
      );

      const notSelectedName = informationalService.filter(
        selection => selection.serviceName.name !== name
      );
      const serviceChecked = selectedName.filter(
        selected => selected.serviceName.properties.service !== item.service
      );

      setInformationalService([
        ...notSelectedName,
        {
          serviceName: {
            name,
            properties: {
              service: [...selectedNamePropertiesService, item.service],
              cost: [...selectedNamePropertiesCost, item.cost]
            }
          }
        }
      ]);
    } else {
      setInformationalService([
        {
          serviceName: {
            name,
            properties: {
              service: item.service,
              cost: item.cost
            }
          }
        }
      ]);
    }
  };
```

Comment: I recommend the values for `service` and `cost` use consistent data types. In your case, the initial values should be an array with one item in them. When you need to change it, you can push new items into the arrays.

Comment: @Hoyen, thank you. Could you elaborate a bit more about what you mean by my values using consistent data types? Do you mean in my example cost: [300], service:["Good"]?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to ignore the part of after your goal and do this:

```
let data = {
serviceName: {
    name: "A",
    properties:{
    cost: 300,
    service:"Good"
    }
}
let olddata = {
serviceName: {
    name: "A",
    properties:{
    cost: 600,
    service:"Bad"
    }
};
let newprops = {},
 dataprops = data.serviceName.properties,
 olddataprops = olddata.serviceName.properties;

for (let prop in dataprops) {
  if (olddataprops[prop]) {
    newprops[prop] = [dataprops[prop], olddataprops[prop]];
  } else {
    newprops[prop] = dataprops[prop];
  }
}
```